# Zend framework 2 BjyAuthorize Controller Guard doesn't work

Tags: zend-framework2, bjyauthorize

Route guard works great, but controller guard doesn't work. I don't use route guard and controller guard simultaneously and I use version 1.4
this is a sample guard that doesn't work :

```
'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller' => array(
                 array('controller' => 'zfcuser','roles' => array()),
        ),
```

Comment: The information you provided is insufficient, and the question text is not clear enough.

What does `doesn't work` mean?

Comment: I will redirect to 403 page. when I want to access zfcuser/login with above controller guard and guest role I will face with 403 page.

Comment: Why did you not add a role then? I am pretty sure you have to set up a  'default_role'.

Comment: empty roles means every roles , default_role has been set to geuest by default configuration

Comment: So It means Only I have this problem!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also. The route guard was working as expected but, when I commented it out and enabled controller guard everything start giving me 403. My problem was the **Zfc-Admin** module: by default activates route guard for zfcadmin route. Hope this helps someone as it took me half of day to nail it!

```
'bjyauthorize' => array(
    'guards' => array(
        'BjyAuthorize\Guard\Route' => array(
            array('route' => 'zfcadmin', 'roles' => array('admin')),
        ),
    ),
),
```